# PHP - Incluir un array dentro del constructor de una clase

Tags: php, array, poo, class, static

En una práctica de PHP POO que estoy haciendo tengo que programar una clase y me gustaría saber cual es la forma adecuada para incluir un array estático dentro del constructor de una clase.

La clase tiene las siguientes características:

La clase **Element** contiene dos propiedades privadas que pueden ser **id** y **name**.

Además la clase contiene un array estático privado que tiene como clave un **id** y como valor el **objeto** **Element** que corresponda con ese **id**.

La clase tiene un constructor con el número de parámetros igual al de propiedades , excluyendo propiedades estáticas.

Además el constructor tiene que añadir en el array estático cada objeto **Element** que se cree.

Este sería mi código:

```
<?php

class Element {

    private $name;
    private $id;
    private static $elements = [];

    function __construct($id, $name) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        self::$elements[$id] = $this;
    }

    function __toString() {
        return $this->id . " " . $this->name;
    }

    static function mostrar() {
        foreach (self::$elements as $valor) {
            echo " " .$valor;
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";

$element1 = new Element("A01", "element1");
$element2 = new Element("A02", "element2");
$element3 = new Element("A03", "element3");

echo "</br>";
echo "Mostrar array elements:";
echo "</br>";

Element::mostrar();
```

Éste código muestra la siguiente salida:

```
Mostrar array elements:
 A01 element1 A02 element2 A03 element3
```

Comment: Y, ¿cuál es tu duda o cuál es el problema?

Comment: Me gustaría saber si el método que he utilizado es la forma más adecuada para incluir un array estático dentro del constructor de una clase o si bien hay otra forma mejor.

Answer (score 0):

*"... me gustaría saber cual es la forma adecuada para incluir un array estático dentro del constructor de una clase."*

Si `$elements` es una propiedad estática de la clase, la forma correcta de referirse a dicha propiedad es la que estás utilizando: **`self::$elements`**, ningún problema en ello.

Ahora bien, en el requerimiento se leen dos cosas **contradictorias**:

1. *"Además la clase contiene un array estático privado que tiene como clave un **id** y como valor el **objeto Element** que corresponda con ese **id**."*
2. *"Además el constructor tiene que añadir en el array estático cada objeto **Element** que se cree."*

Supongamos que creas `4` instancias de la clase, pero en `2` de ellas pones el mismo `id`. Esta asignación: `self::$elements[$id] = $this;` se quedará con la última instancia creada con respecto a ese `$id` (caso 1 satisfecho), PERO `$elements` tendrá `3` instancias, no `4` que son las que se habrán creado en realidad (caso 2 no satisfecho).

Vamos a verlo con un ejemplo:

```
class Element {

    private $name;
    private $id;
    private static $elements = [];
    /*
        Agrego estas dos propiedades
        para prueba diferenciada
        */
     private static $caseOne = [];
     private static $caseTwo = [];
   
    function __construct($id, $name) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        self::$elements[$id] = $this;
        self::$caseOne[$id] = $this;
        self::$caseTwo[] = $this;           
    }

    function __toString() {
        return $this->id . " " . $this->name;
    }

    static function mostrar() {
        echo "Contenido de caseOne:".PHP_EOL;
        var_dump(self::$caseOne);
        echo "Contenido de caseTwo:".PHP_EOL;
        var_dump(self::$caseTwo);

        foreach (self::$elements as $valor) {
            //echo " " .$valor;
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";

$element1 = new Element("A01", "element1");
$element2 = new Element("A02", "element2");
$element3 = new Element("A03", "element3");
$element4 = new Element("A03", "element3");

echo "</br>";
echo "Mostrar array elements:";
echo "</br>";

Element::mostrar();
```

**Salida:**

```
Contenido de caseOne:

array(3) {
  ["A01"]=>
  object(Element)#1 (2) {
    ["name":"Element":private]=>
    string(8) "element1"
    ["id":"Element":private]=>
    string(3) "A01"
  }
  ["A02"]=>
  object(Element)#2 (2) {
    ["name":"Element":private]=>
    string(8) "element2"
    ["id":"Element":private]=>
    string(3) "A02"
  }
  ["A03"]=>
  object(Element)#4 (2) {
    ["name":"Element":private]=>
    string(8) "element3"
    ["id":"Element":private]=>
    string(3) "A03"
  }
}


Contenido de caseTwo:

array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(Element)#1 (2) {
    ["name":"Element":private]=>
    string(8) "element1"
    ["id":"Element":private]=>
    string(3) "A01"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(Element)#2 (2) {
    ["name":"Element":private]=>
    string(8) "element2"
    ["id":"Element":private]=>
    string(3) "A02"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(Element)#3 (2) {
    ["name":"Element":private]=>
    string(8) "element3"
    ["id":"Element":private]=>
    string(3) "A03"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(Element)#4 (2) {
    ["name":"Element":private]=>
    string(8) "element3"
    ["id":"Element":private]=>
    string(3) "A03"
  }
}
```